# How can I make a website homepage showing everything on screen (no scrollbars)?

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I'm trying to make a simple (responsive) website with a homepage containing:

- header
- background image
- footer

but I can't find a way to see header, background image and footer all together in the "very first screen", without the need of scrolling down the page. I've searched all over the internet and on this forum but I can't find a solution that fits my needs.

To make the website responsive I'm using w3.css --> http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp

and these are the files I'm using http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/Hhb6FmUY/file.html

I hope that my question is clear and that somebody can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I do not download files from SO.

But I made a very basic template for you that includes a header, background, and footer on a single page with **NO** scroll.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav></nav>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
  background: blue;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/xwyJxq)